# Improve the speed of insert in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

I want to insert 700 million rows to a table which is defined in a following way.

```
CREATE TABLE KeywordIndex (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 keyValue VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, postings LONGTEXT NOT NULL);
```

To insert data in the table I first check if the keyValue exists I update the value of postings by concatenating new value to old value. Otherwise, insert data as a new row of the table. Also, if the size of postings is bigger than its definition I consider a new row to write extension of postings of the keyValue. In my implementation, inserting 70,294 entry took 12 hours!!!!

( I am not a database expert, so the code I've written could be based on wrong foundations. Please help me to understand my mistakes :) )

I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033060/how-to-improve-insert-performance-on-a-very-large-mysql-table) but I could not find a solution for my problem.

I add code that I wrote to do this process.

```
 public void writeTermIndex(
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<TermPosting>> finalInvertedLists) {

        try {


            for (String key : finalInvertedLists.keySet()) {

                     int exist=ExistTerm("KeywordIndex",key);
                     ArrayList<TermPosting> currentTermPostings=finalInvertedLists.get(key);
                      if (exist>0)
                      {
                          String postings=null;
                          String query = "select postings from KeywordIndex where keyValue=?";

                          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                          preparedStmt.setString (1, key);    
                          ResultSet  rs=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
                          if(rs.next())
                              postings=rs.getString("postings");

                          postings=postings+convertTermPostingsToString(currentTermPostings);

                          if(getByteSize(postings)>65530)
                                insertUpdatePostingList("KeywordIndex",key,postings);
                          else{

                              updatePosting("KeywordIndex",key,postings);
                              rs.close();
                              preparedStmt.close();
                          }

                      }

                      else
                      {
                          String postings=convertTermPostingsToString(currentTermPostings);
                          if(getByteSize(postings)>65530)
                            insertPostingList("KeywordIndex",key,postings);

                          else
                              insetToHashmap("KeywordIndex",key,postings);
                      }

                }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Exactly how is this code not working?

Comment: Consider [bulk load](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) then call a procedure to combine records between the tables, then drop the bulk loaded table.  The individual calls back and forth from your application to database are going to be SLOW...  The overhead for packet, overhead for database connection and call.  IMO better off bulk loading and let the database "MERGE" the sets in a procedure to eliminate traffic and overhead.   The procedure is just two statements insert all non existing records, update existing records.  so much faster all in db

Comment: @MarcB it works but **slowly**.

Comment: @xQbert Could you please explain more? what do you mean by combine records between tables? I only have one table. I only one time connect to my database.

Comment: The bulk Load takes the date from the source file containing the 700 million rows and loads it into a second table.  once the database has both tables the queries to combine the two into one become simple.  Add index on keys to loaded table. Then Insert into original table from loaded table where the id in loaded table is not in original table.  Then update original table from loaded table setting the new value = oldvalue + new value.  then drop the loaded table. The logic to combine is done in the database. Overhead of processing each row from app server to db server is just too slow.

Comment: Put another way.... If you're goal is to eat all the french fries as fast as you can... do you eat them one at a time or 3-5 at a time?  You eat as many as you can at once.  Record by Record processing in a Relational Database is SLOW.  Relational databases work better on Set based logic.  So load your raw data, and process 2 sets those already in the original table, and those not.

Comment: @xQbert many thanks.

Comment: To expand on the french fry example: Would you want the restaurant to give you one at a time, a box, or a plate, or as many as they could and then leave it up to you to figure out how to eat them?  Personally I'd ask for all they could give me at once.  One at a time would just be too slow ;P

Comment: @xQbert could you help me how can I write the code in your way. I understand your idea.

Comment: The site isn't about generating code, it's about helping when you encounter problems.  Show us some code where your'e struggling and we'll help.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html is an example of loading a table from a file.  and here's a [bulk loader class](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) that uses the load statement to create /populate the table!

Comment: @xQbert I read data from a HashMap not a file and I insert in different way for each condition like when the length of posting is more than 65530 add a new row otherwise old data and new data are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using `executeBatch()` for **insert** (I'm not talking about the load part of your request). Depending on your database, performances can change a lot (see benchmark at the end of this [page](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/16/what-you-didnt-know-about-jdbc-batch/))(I once tested it with oracle database)

Something like :

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insertQuerry);

    for (/*...*/) {
        statement.clearParameters();
        statement.setString(1, "Hi");                   
        statement.addBatch();
    }

    statement.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException se) {
    //Handle exception
} finally {
    //Close everything
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more you said in insertion part I use executeBatch but I insert after some checking that this keyValue is exist or not? Could you please explain with more details