# how can we update large set of data in solr which is already indexed

Tags: mysql, solr

I implemented for one of my client where i indexed lot of rows from one of the tables in collection of solr.the number was around 90,00,000 and is constantly growing.
Now  i need to update the indexed documents real time.how can i do that.
I have feeds coming from third party urls and getting stored in mysql table and then i m updating in solr data import handler,the same way when i indexed the documents initially.But this  update is taking long time.I need to update the indexes real time in the day.whats the better approach for that.I searched about notch which works as a web crawler which will help in indexing and updating quickly.Is there any other way which is reliable and less time taking..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the DataImportHandler delta import not do what you want?

Comment: @DavidGeorge-Yes.i think u r correct.i can use that.i will do a test on that.can u please answer one point here before updating indexes in solr,its taking lot of time to update the mysql db.By Any way i can reduce that time as there 90,00,000 and counting rows.

Comment: I can't tell you anything about mysql I'm afraid. There are some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033060/how-to-improve-insert-performance-on-a-very-large-mysql-table How frequently are you updating the database?

Comment: i would be updating 2-3 real times.how about mongodb

Comment: I was just thinking that you might want to index directly from your incoming feeds with the database being useful if you need to reindex at some point. (schema change)

Comment: @DavidGeorge ok.you mean to say as index upgrade in solr should be in syncing process with database upgrade with feeds coming in rather than updating solr index one time after complete database upgrade.Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, update solr from your feed. Keep the database as a source of record if you need to do an entire reindex.

Comment: @DavidGeorge  ok.So i need to use csv import handler for updating with feeds as feeds are in csv.correct?